# Как сделать проверку что если хотя бы один чек бокс выбран?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день есть такой функционал

При клике выбирается чек- бокс. Важный вопрос, как сделать проверку что если хотя бы один чек бокс из пунктов выбрано - то parent должен иметь класс active
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    const parent = document.querySelector('#parent')

    parent.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        const inputChecked = this.document.querySelector('input:checked')
        parent.classList.contains('active') && parent.classList.remove('active');
        !!inputChecked && parent.classList.add('active');
    })
```

```css
#parent {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
}
#parent.active {
  background-color: gainsboro;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">

    <label for="checkbox_1">
        <input id="checkbox_1" type="checkbox" /> 1
    </label>

    <label for="checkbox_2">
        <input id="checkbox_2" type="checkbox" /> 2
    </label>

    <label for="checkbox_3">
        <input id="checkbox_3" type="checkbox" /> 3
    </label>

    <label for="checkbox_4">
        <input id="checkbox_4" type="checkbox" /> 4
    </label>

</div>
```

**Так без цикла**

```
<div id="parent">

    <label for="checkbox_1">
        <input id="checkbox_1" type="checkbox" /> 1
    </label>

    <label for="checkbox_2">
        <input id="checkbox_2" type="checkbox" /> 2
    </label>

    <label for="checkbox_3">
        <input id="checkbox_3" type="checkbox" /> 3
    </label>

    <label for="checkbox_4">
        <input id="checkbox_4" type="checkbox" /> 4
    </label>

</div>

<script>

    const parent = document.querySelector('#parent')

    parent.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        const inputChecked = this.document.querySelector('input:checked')
        parent.classList.contains('active') && parent.classList.remove('active');
        !!inputChecked && parent.classList.add('active');
    })

</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Вот простой пример как ето можно сделать :

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(cb => cb.addEventListener('change', e => {
  const countChecked = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
  e.target.closest('.parent').classList.toggle('active', countChecked);
}));
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Получить кол-во выбранных элементов:

```
var count = $(':checkbox:checked').length;
```

Потом проверяешь на если не 0, делаешь свои действия.